# ETL script to update table using INSERT INTO ....ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: python, mysql

I have searched stack overflow for possible solutions, and could not find one.  Please donot mark as duplicate.

I am working on a ETL script, to perform UPSERTs to a mysql table.

The emp table has primary keys (id, emp_name), and now I have removed AUTO INCREMENT to a column ID, since we were having huge gaps in the ID number when there are more UPDATEs to existing records.

Now I would like to provide my own ID value which would be sequential (by using MAX(ID) from the table).  I am getting some issues, in that the MAX(ID)+1 is not getting inserted to the table.  Please help fix this issue.

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=url, user=uname, password=pwd, database=dbase)
cur = conn.cursor()

insertQry = "INSERT INTO emp (id, emp_name, dept, designation, address1, city, state, active_start_date, is_active) SELECT (SELECT coalesce(MAX(ID),0) + 1 FROM atlas.emp) id, tmp.emp_name, tmp.dept, tmp.designation, tmp.address1, tmp.city, tmp.state, tmp.active_start_date, tmp.is_active from EMP_STG tmp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dept=tmp.dept, designation=tmp.designation, address1=tmp.address1, city=tmp.city, state=tmp.state, active_start_date=tmp.active_start_date, is_active =tmp.is_active ;"

n = cur.execute(loadQry)
print (" CURSOR status :", n)
```

Comment: Your title and your question are not related. What is your question -- how MySQL parses addition within queries, or performing upserts in MySQL?

Comment: If i have 10 records to insert, I would like to fetch max of ID from the emp table, and assign to every record that is being inserted, to the same emp table.  Like a select max(ID)+1 from emp, and pass this as a value parameter in INSERT statement.

Comment: `(SELECT coalesce(MAX(ID),0) + 1 FROM atlas.emp)` is the same value for every row in tmp, so only one new row gets inserted, the rest updates that row. Just reactive the autoincrement and live with the gaps. Everyone does it. If you really really do not want to do that: calculate the row number in tmp and add that to the value of `(SELECT coalesce(MAX(ID),0) + 1 FROM atlas.emp) + tmp.rownumber`. There are numerous questions on stackoverflow where you can find code to calculate the row number (and if you e.g. fill tmp in some php loop, you can even count and add the rownumber directly there).